# Can "body" be replaced with "number" in this sentence?

Tags: nouns

> He  left a very large **body** of drawings.

I understand what "body" means in this sentence, but it's possible to replace it with a word like "number". I think body has a emotional touch in it.

Will a change occur if I replace *body* with *number*?

Answer (score 1):

No, the general idea of the sentence will stay the same. Basically says that he left numerous drawings. The "slightly more specific meaning" attaching to ***body*** is the implication that collectively, the drawings form a "coherent whole". The same way a real biological body has features and functions that go beyond anything directly manifest in the individual cells that make up that body.

Comment: The "slightly more specific meaning" attaching to ***body*** is the implication that collectively, the drawings form a "coherent whole". The same way a real biological body has features and functions that go beyond anything directly manifest in the individual cells that make up that body.

Comment: I like that phrasing, can I borrow it for my answer?

Comment: Please do! My main reason for posting the comment is in hopes that you might consider making an edit to improve your answer. Which is perfectly correct so far as it goes, but I do think that *large number of things that can/should be considered **as a whole collection*** is an important implication of the word ***body*** in OP's context, so it's well worth explicitly making the point in your answer. Besides which it's a useful reminder to non-native speakers that there's usually a good ***reason*** why we use this particular (biological) metaphor in this context.

Comment: (Note that OP has drawn the inappropriate implication / association between ***body*** and ***emotional***, so it would obviously be useful for him! :)

Comment: ...warming to my theme, I'd go so far as to suggest that changing ***body*** to ***number*** could significantly affect how the statement might be interpreted. To me, ***number*** actually implies the drawings are numerous, but ***not** capable of being treated as a whole* (i.e. - they're just a bewildering mishmash of different drawings with no real connection apart from all having come from the same artist, which might imply they're just "throwaway" pieces, rather than a collection of great art).

Comment: I agree that that body means collective, but I do think that generally average readers who see either of those words, number or body, won't perceive any real difference in meaning like we do. (We tend to analyze a bit more) ;)

Comment: Maybe. But if you look at how writers have used [*a **body** of legal principles*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+body+of+legal+principles%22) and compare these to [*a **number** of legal principles*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+number+of+legal+principles%22) (which is about equally common), you might change your mind. I think the distinction is often quite relevant, and expressed quite deliberately.